# Ensure generic parameter is a concrete type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method that uses the generic parameter as the key of a dictionary:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> myCollection) where T : IMyInterface
{
    var smthg = MyDictionary[typeof(T)];
    //...
}
```

This code works well. But of course, if you call it like that:

```
MyMethod(myCollectionOfT.Cast<IMyInterface>());
```

`T` will be `IMyInterface` (not a class that implements `IMyInterface`), and the dictionary won't have the key (which is normal).

I can easily have an exception thrown when the problem occurs:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(IMyInterface)) throw new ArgumentException("The generic parameter should be strongly typed.", "T");
```

But is there a way (constraint or something) to have a compile-time error when your call uses the interface instead of a class that implements it?

Edit:

**D Stanley** gave a solution: the `new()` constraint would garantee that `T` is not an interface.

Comment: Do you want it to just not be _that_ interface?  what if it were a _different_ interface that extended `IMyInterface`?

Comment: The only constraint that would prevent you from using the interface would be `new()`, which requires that the concrete type have a public, parameterless constructor.

Comment: Also what are you _doing_ with the dictionary?  It woulds like you're using generics when the code underneath isn't really _generic_.  Maybe you want overloads instead?

Comment: @DStanley Works well with the new(), thx. As for the dictionary itself, it isn't really generic but the rest of my method's code is (and has to be) generic. Of course, I could call GetType() on the first element, unless my collection is empty...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use the `class` constraint if you're dealing with reference types.</strike> EDIT: Actually, that matches "just" interfaces as well. Oh well.

It's really more of a design problem - you're using interfaces (in broader sense) in a functionally non-virtual way. What if I do

```
MyMethod(MyListOfDerivedClass.Cast<MyBaseClass>())
```

?

Since you're violating the design of interfaces and inheritance, you must ensure that your own rules aren't broken. You can't rely on the compiler or the usual OOP design rules, since you're violating those.

By designing your generic method to accept any argument of type `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`, you're saying that any implementation of `IMyInterface` should be valid. The same way, it doesn't matter if the items in the enumerable are of different types as long as they all implement `IMyInterface` properly. It's the same thing with any method, regardless of whether it's generic or not. What you're doing is akin to having a method that accepts `Control`, but only works when you actually pass `Label` or `Button`, and fails for anything else, including types *derived* from `Label` or `Button`.

Comment: `class` would not prevent using the interface; it just ensures that the type is a _reference type_.

Comment: @DStanley Chmm, you're right. That means a lot of fun when you pass a `struct` as an interface :/

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this code

```
public void MyMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> myCollection) where T : IMyInterface, class, new()
{
    var smthg = MyDictionary[typeof(T)];
    //...
}
```

according to [MSDN Constraints on Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)
**Edit:**
class means that T must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type. so you can use new() to check that T is class if your constructor is public.

Comment: `class` would not prevent you from using the interface as the type parameter; it just ensures that the type is a _reference type_.